# change of product image thumbnail color

Tags: product-images, frontend, media-images

i want to change the background color of product image on product page.as by default the color is white but can same be changed ?

we have cropped images but as per main image the background doesn't match.
as can be seen in image the background is white can a custom color be set on the same.
[image]

Comment: What Magento version are you using?

Comment: magento 2.2.0 ( community )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override below file in your theme :

> /lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less

In your theme

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less

Go to Line No. 1014

```
.fotorama__stage {
   background: #333333; /*Add background color */
}
```

Comment: Is that working for you please vote so another people use same, Thanks